# By date meaning

Tags: prepositions

"Please be advised that The Company has notified us that they will disable our accounts on The Platform by July 21, 2018."

I have to translate this statement, but I can't understand what 'by' means.

Which is right meaning?

1. Disable duration : July 21st ~ End of the World
2. Disable duration : Today ~ July 21st

Answer (score 1):

3. any time up to and including July 21.

**by**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/by)

> 6. Not later than x time and/or date